# Preventing duplicate strings in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string in my code which concatenates email addresses from various tables in the database and then shows up in outlook in the cc field.

all i want is to filter the string so that the string does not contain any duplicate email address. in other words, i do not want a single email address to be repeated again in the output.

please help

```
DataSet ds = DatabaseFunctions.getEmailsBySPROC("getEmailByCircuit", sql_CircuitEmail);

if (ds != null)
{
    for (int idx = 0; idx < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; idx++)
    {
        emailList = emailList + ds.Tables[0].Rows[idx]["Email"].ToString() + ";";
    }
}
```

thats the code to retireve from one table..

there another code to retrive from another table..
\and the string is email list seperated by ; semicolon

Comment: Give us some example-code to work with. Give us some examples of the string as it is now, and how you want it to look. Basically: put a bit more effort in your question.. That is; if you want your problem solved :)

Comment: What is the intermediate value of the email addresses?  A list or array?  A comma-separated string?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first and most obvious suggestion is to filter it out on the DB side of things; meaning when retrieving the data from the DB add a "distinct" clause if possible so that you only get distinct email addresses.

Otherwise, you can add all the email addresses to a HashSet<string> which automatically filters out duplicates for you.

Re your code:

```
DataSet ds = DatabaseFunctions.getEmailsBySPROC("getEmailByCircuit", sql_CircuitEmail);

if (ds != null)
{
    DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
    HashSet<string> emails = new HashSet<string>();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < table.Rows.Count; idx++)
    {
        emails.Add(table.Rows[idx]["Email"].ToString());
    }
}

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string email in emails)
{
    result.Append(email + ";");
}

emailList = result.ToString();
```

Comment: Beat me to it with HashSet<string>!

Comment: Note that a HashSet is unordered. In the OP's case (cc emails) it doesn't matter; this is just a caveat for those cases where it does.

Answer (score 4):

```
var emails = new HashSet<String>();
var email = " Blah@blah.com ".Trim().ToLower();
emails.Add(email);
```

Comment: The point of the HashSet is that you don't need the if check. You just add it and the HashSet internally weeds out dupes.

Comment: It is, *unless* you want to throw an exception when a duplicate is added. HashSet won't throw anything, it just won't add it.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace UniqueEmailAddresses
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string emailList
            = "bob@example.com; sally@example.com; fred@example.com; sally@example.com";
            var result = emailList.Replace(" ", "").Split(';').Distinct();
            foreach( var addy in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(addy);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
bob@example.com
sally@example.com
fred@example.com
```

Sally appears only once.

Answer (score 1):

As BFree said, you could (assuming you're not pulling a significant amount of records from the DB) easily just do the following:

```
var emails = new HashSet<string>(yourStrings);
```

It should automatically filter them out and you could easily iterate using the HashSet collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DataSet ds = DatabaseFunctions.getEmailsBySPROC("getEmailByCircuit", sql_CircuitEmail);
 if (ds != null)
 {
     for (int idx = 0; idx < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; idx++)
     {
         emailList = emailList + ds.Tables[0].Rows[idx]["Email"].ToString() + ";";
     }
 }
```

thats picked from one table...and then i do the same to pick it up from antoher table,,

Answer (score 0):

add to a collection and than collection contains.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

if (!list.contains("mail") )
{
  list.add("mail");
}
```

Comment: This will most likely be very slow.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Putting aside HashSet being more appropriate, the performance of List<T> isn't a problem. It performs just fine and if all you are doing is adding Email addresses to a CC in Outlook the difference is almost certainly going to be sub-second. If there are enough addresses to make a difference, sending the email via Outlook is itself going to be a problem.

Comment: I agree but there is no reason to ignore such a performance hit with such an obvious improvement available.

Comment: Is there something even more granular than Micro Optimization?